# I have a mutt with a weird body shape. I can't seem to find a winter jacket that fits him

Tags: dogs, winter

I have a question. I have a rat terrier / English bull / unidentified (lol) dog mutt. We got a bit of extra cold winter here on the Northeast coast this year. I bought 3 coats for him from Amazon but none of them fits him! He has a really big chest, wide neck, but learn long lower body, also short legs...

Just curious, for anyone who has a mutt which a unique body shape, do you guys find shopping for clothes or any any winter gear frustrating?

Thank you in advance for your feedback and recommendation!

Comment: Odd question but are there any local pet shops with that kinda thing? Might be a good idea to find somewhere where you can actually see what it looks like before you buy

Answer (score 1):

My pitbull half breed has kind of same problem.
It's likely that you wont find anything online. Almost every adjustable coat is only adjustable around their belly, but the chest and neck has to fit.
You have 2 options.

1) look for it locally so you can test it.

2) harnesses are way more adjustable. You could go on DIY and make a jacket over a fit harness.